# ORA - 01400 : Cannot Insert into null (One to Many bidrectional) JPA having Composite Keys

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, orm

When I'm trying to save the child table, the insert query fired doesn't contain the foreign key field. The insert query that JPA fires doesn't contain the foreign key column. Here are the models and their composite key classes :

```
@Embeddable
public class EwpPk implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3231628074628968344L;

@Column(name = "ewp_sid", nullable = false)
private Long sid

@Column(name = "PRTN_KEY", nullable = false)
private Date partitionDate;

@Column(name = "SUB_PRTN_SEQ_NUM", nullable = false)
private int sequenceNumber;

}

@Table(name = "EWP")
public class Ewp implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7232535288636665348L;

@EmbeddedId
private EwpPk modelid;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Eap)
@MapsId("e_modelid")
@joinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name="eap_sid", nullable=false),
  @JoinColumn(name="PRTN_KEY", nullable=false),
  @JoinColumn(name="SUB_PRTN_SEQ_NUM", nullable=false)
})
private Eap eap;

public class EnrolledAccountRangePartitionedModel implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 700193113967839613L;

@EmbeddedId
private EapPk e_modelid;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Ewp.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "eap")
private list<Ewp> ewpList;

}

@Embeddable
public class EapPk implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4696018718017450273L;

@Column(name = "Eap_sid", nullable = false)
private Long eapsid;

@Column(name = "PRTN_KEY", nullable = false)
private Date partitionDate;

@Column(name = "SUB_PRTN_SEQ_NUM", nullable = false)
private int sequenceNumber;
```

I get this error ORA - 01400 : Cannot Insert into null

Comment: Please add your code as a text

Comment: I have added code as text